# How to specify a function as an optional parameter to a hook with a default value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to write a custom hook in a react app using TypeScript that can take several, optional callback functions. However I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onUpdate'). I write an interface like this:

```
interface UseMyHookProps {
  onConnect:() => void;
  onUpdate?:() => void;
  onDisconnect?:() => {};
}
```

And then my hook like this:

```
const useMyHook = ({ onConnect = () => {}, onUpdate = () => {}, onDisconnect = () => {} }: UseMyHookProps) => {
  ...
  // call the callback if defined.
  onUpdate();
};
```

finally I call the hook in a component function like this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  useMyHook();
  ...
};
```

I don't understand why I get this error. I say the callback is optional and provide a default argument of a void function that does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are providing default values only for the attributes of the object, but not for the object itself which can still be `undefined` if you call the hook without parameters.

You can easily solve that by defaulting the hook's parameter to an empty object `= {}`

```
  const useMyHook = ({
    onConnect = () => {},
    onUpdate = () => {},
    onDisconnect = () => {},
  }: UseMyHookProps = {}) => { // <<<<
    // call the callback if defined.
    onUpdate();
  };
```

The version below is exactly the same thing but more verbose, you can see that without defaulting `params = {}`, `params` would be undefined and the object destructuring below would fail

```
  const useMyHook = (params: UseMyHookProps = {}) => {
    const {
      onConnect = () => {},
      onUpdate = () => {},
      onDisconnect = () => {},
    } = params

    // call the callback if defined.
    onUpdate();
  };
```